# Convergence under rank correlation

Tags: finance, correlation

I have a following setup:
Let $c\in{\Bbb R}$, $R^2\in [0,1]$ and $\Psi,\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\ldots$ independent random variables on
a probability space $(\Omega,{\cal A},{\Bbb P})$.  Define the ability-to-pay variables by 
\begin{equation}
A_j(R^2):=\sqrt{R^{2}}\Psi+\sqrt{1-R^{2}}\varepsilon_j
\end{equation}
for $j\in{\Bbb N}$. The unconditional and conditional default probabilities are respectively defined by 
\begin{eqnarray}
p(R^2) & := & {\Bbb P}(A_j\leq c)={\Bbb P}(\sqrt{R^{2}}\Psi+\sqrt{1-R^{2}}\varepsilon_j\leq c), \\
p(\psi,R^2) & := & {\Bbb P}(\sqrt{R^{2}}\psi+\sqrt{1-R^{2}}\varepsilon_j\leq c)
\end{eqnarray}
for $\Psi\in{\Bbb R}$ and any $j\in{\Bbb N}$. Default indicators and default counts are
defined by $$ I_j(R^2):={\bf 1}_{\{A_j(R^2)\leq c\}}$$ and $$D_n(R^2):=\sum_{j=1}^n I_j(R^2)$$
for $n\in{\Bbb N}$.

Let $X$ be a random variable and assume that the random variables
 $\Psi,X $ are standardized and
follow a multivariate normal distribution. It is known that conditional on $\Psi$, $\frac{D_n(R^2)}{n}$ coverges in probability to $p(\Psi,R^2)$

I want to understand how to show following:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\rho_{\tau}(X,D_n(R^2))=\rho_{\tau}(X,p(\Psi,R^2))$$
where $\rho_{\tau}$ denotes Kendall's Tau.

Thank you in advance. Any ideas on the proof are very welcome, as well as the assesment of its complexity :)

Best,
Dima